# Google cloud load balancer: Redirect host and add base path while keeping the remaining path intact

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I want to redirect the host of my incoming url and add a base path to it. Using the pathRedirect rule helps me achieve this, but it strips out any original path original url had.

abc.mydomain.com/original/path should redirect to

abc.mydomain2.com/base_path/original/path

I tried adding a pathRedirect rule but it will just redirect to that specific path, stripping any original path the url had.

Comment: What is the Load balancer type (e.g., GCP HTTP(S))?
what Redirect type (301 or 302)?
do you have any pathRedirect rule ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.